# Dual boot win 7 and 10

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-10

I installed win 10 hoping to dual boot with win 7. But it does not work. Can this be done? What I mean is can you trust Microsofts installer to dual boot your system? If not can I fix it? If my prior installation is lost can I add a new one? I installed a secondary drive and issued the command

```
bcdboot "I:\Windows"
```

and this added an option, now I have two Windows 7 options. But neither work, they both begin to start Win 7 (I see the "Starting" screen but then they switch to Win 10.

I tried the dual boot repair tool but it did not help.  I also downloaded the visual bcd tool.  But I cant get either windows 7 to boot.  The machine booted windows 7 just fine before.  Here is the output of BCDEdit

```
Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=C:
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {default}
resumeobject            {6b8c82a8-baf3-11e5-9bdb-7446a0991d60}
displayorder            {default}
                        {6b8c82a7-baf3-11e5-9bdb-7446a0991d60}
                        {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {default}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 10
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {6b8c82a8-baf3-11e5-9bdb-7446a0991d60}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {6b8c82a7-baf3-11e5-9bdb-7446a0991d60}
device                  partition=I:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-us
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
osdevice                partition=I:
systemroot              \windows
resumeobject            {6b8c82a6-baf3-11e5-9bdb-7446a0991d60}
nx                      OptIn
detecthal               Yes

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  locate=\Windows\system32\winload.exe
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoveryenabled         No
osdevice                locate=\Windows
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {5586dd33-361b-11e0-8df8-0018716eb820}
nx                      OptIn
```

I could reinstall everything if I must but I would prefer not to go that route.

Comment: I have always used Easy BCD for this, just hit the download button, no need to register.  http://neosmart.net/Download/Register

Comment: You appear to have two entries that are called "Windows 7", but one of them looks like it will go to Windows 10 (the installation on the C partition).

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Boot sequence for Windows 7/10 on BIOS/MBR is:

1) MBR on first disk

2) PBR of active partition on first disk

3) boot manager from active partition first disk (which uses BCD for getting boot loader settings and also other settings)

When you use two different OS (Windows 7 and Windows 10) **on active partition first disk Windows 10 boot manager must be installed**.

**For easily fixing dual boot issues** - [Dual-boot Repair Windows 10 utility](https://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html). Has one click automatic solution for fixing dual-boot issues. Automatic repair also makes a backup of current BCD so you can restore BCD if needed.

Using "Repair BCD" option of the tool you can easily add a boot loader for the specified Windows system (Windows 7/8/10).

Visual BCD Editor is for fine tuning of boot loaders but can also create/delete loaders, backup/restore BCD. Needs some basic BCD knowledge. You need even more knowledge when using bcdedit.

bcdedit, bcdboot are system tools and access is limited to admin account. Microsoft did not create a nice boot related GUI tool on purpose. I think to limit access for novice users to manipulate boot files.

---

EDIT: - How have you managed to create such an impossible loader?

This is unique!

```
identifier              {current}
device                  locate=\Windows\system32\winload.exe
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  en-US
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoveryenabled         No
osdevice                locate=\Windows
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {5586dd33-361b-11e0-8df8-0018716eb820}
nx                      OptIn
```

"device" and "osdevice" should be real, virtual(vhd) or ram(wim) devices.
Usually they are mapped hard disk partition (where the OS is installed).